# How to show unique values from a column in a pie chart?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get unique values of the "Sector" column and display them on a pie chart.
For example for investments, the pie chart should be able to display investments along with the sum of all the values from the "Average total price" column.
Still trying to figure out on how should i procede.

[image: Screenshot of google spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `=query` ?

```
=query(D:F, "SELECT D, sum(E), sum(F) group by D")
```